# onchange event not working in mvc razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor-pages

I am adding an email address and a contact no validation but both are not working.

I enter this email address and then insert it successfully in database:

```
asda
```

I enter this contact no and then insert it successfully in database:

```
1234
```

it gives an alert invalid but issue is when I press the button then successfully insert the database.

.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Career";
}

<h2>Career</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Career", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 style="text-align:center">Upload Form</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>EmailId:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="useremailid" placeholder="Please Enter EmailAddress" onchange="validateEmail()" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>ContactNo:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="usercontactno" placeholder="Please Enter ContactNo" onchange="validateContactNo()" title="Enter 10 digit mobile number" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Resume:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="file" name="userresume" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="btn bg-success" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateEmail() {
        var text = document.getElementsByName("useremailid").value;
        var regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        if (regx.test(text))
            alert("valid");
        else
            alert("invalid");
    }

    function validateContactNo() {
        var text = document.getElementsByName("usercontactno").value;
        var regx = /\d{10}/;

        if (regx.test(text))
            alert("valid");
        else
            alert("invalid");
    }

</script>
```

[image]

After the alert pops up, then press the button, then store the **data(asd emailaddress)** successfully in the database.

What I am trying:

**I am trying on button click but it's also not working**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="useremailid" placeholder="Please Enter EmailAddress"  required />

<input class="form-control" type="number" name="usercontactno" placeholder="Please Enter ContactNo" required />

<input class="btn bg-success" type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {

                var emailid = document.getElementsByName("useremailid").value;
                var regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

            if (emailid) {
                if (regx.test(text))
                    alert("valid");
                else
                    alert("invalid");
            }

            var contactno = document.getElementsByName("usercontactno").value;
            var regx = /\d{10}/;

            if (contactno) {

                if (regx.test(text))
                    alert("valid");
                else
                    alert("invalid");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**I am trying on submit form but it's also not working**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Career", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmsubmit" }))
{

  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="useremailid" placeholder="Please Enter EmailAddress" required />


      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="usercontactno" placeholder="Please Enter ContactNo" required />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#frmsubmit').submit(function () {

            var emailid = document.getElementsByName("useremailid").value;
            var regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

            if (emailid) {
                if (regx.test(text))
                    alert("valid");
                else
                    alert("invalid");
            }

            var contactno = document.getElementsByName("usercontactno").value;
            var regx = /\d{10}/;

            if (contactno) {

                if (regx.test(text))
                    alert("valid");
                else
                    alert("invalid");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to contactno only allow 10 digit

Comment: That's because the validation is attached to the textboxes. No validation happens at the point when the button is pressed. You aren't using the results of the validation to affect the ability to submit.

Comment: @ADyson as you said I try on button click but not work https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqvK5.png

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Code is text. But anyway all you've done there is put some functions inside another function. You aren't actually **executing** those functions. I'm worried that you don't understand some basic things about how to use JavaScript. Maybe a little more study of the fundamentals would be beneficial

Comment: Also, button clicking isn't always the only way to submit a form. To catch all cases you'd be better to handle the _form's_ "submit" event rather than the button's click event.

Comment: I try the submit form but also not worked see I edit my question trying and trying but not work validation

Comment: This is better, but when you are deciding if the data is valid or not, the only thing you're doing with that info is displaying an alert. This tells the user the result, but it doesn't change the behaviour of the form submission in any way. Again I think you're missing a basic understanding of some fundamentals - why would you imagine that displaying an alert would tell the browser not to submit the form? A little bit of research would tell you that you need to `return false;` from the function whenever the data is invalid - this tells the browser not to continue submitting.

Comment: P.S. Are you aware that you actually don't need any of this JavaScript code at all? The exact same validation can be done easily using HTML5 validation attributes in your form, and the browser will then automatically stop the submission if the validation fails, without you needing to write extra code. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern for more details.

Comment: @ADyson ```if (emailid) {
                if (regx.test(text)) {
                    debugger
                    alert("valid");
                }
                else {
                    debugger
                    alert("invalid");
                    return false;
                }
            }```  I write the return false but when I write asd still submit the data

Comment: @ADyson and this is not worked ```pattern="[0-9]{3}"``` I already try this before post the question

Comment: The alert may be a problem because it pauses the JS execution, but the form may continue to submit. Remove the alert and find a different way to display the message to the user.

Comment: Why would `pattern="[0-9]{3}"` be any use to you? That isn't the same as either of the expressions you've used in your code. Bear in mind that you'd have to change your "number" input to a "text" input before the pattern will work - the documentation tells you which types of inputs it works with. For number inputs if you simply want to check the length of the input then set the `max` property instead.

Comment: @ADyson still I am struggling with validation and not work in browser

Comment: Ok but that's too vague for me to help you. I can only help you if you tell me a specific problem with specific code.

Comment: You will have a script error because `text` is not defined. (Tell your browser to preserve the console log between requests and you can see it.) Where did you expect that value to come from? You need to test `emailid` instead. Same with the other one, you'd need to test `contactno`.

Comment: @ADyson hey I already try with the text also not work ```if (regx.text(text)) {```

Comment: Huh? Read my comment again more carefully please. I'm telling you **not** to use `text`. it doesn't exist, does it? It has no value. You never defined any such variable.

Comment: Change that and it's fine. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/96kg8bo3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of the code will work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frmsubmit').submit(function() {

    var emailid = document.getElementById("useremailid").value;
    var regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if (emailid) {
      if (regx.test(emailid))
        alert("valid");
      else
        alert("invalid");
      return false;
    }

    var contactno = document.getElementById("usercontactno").value;
    var regx = /\d{10}/;

    if (contactno) {

      if (regx.test(contactno))
        alert("valid");
      else
        alert("invalid");
      return false;

    }
  })
});
```

You were validating the wrong variable in your regular expression, and (in the original version of the question) not running the validation when the form was actually being submitted.

Comment: thanks for your time I learn something new today thank you adyson